# Why does my Doctrine DBAL query return no results when quoted?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm using the Doctrine DataBase Abstraction Layer (DBAL) to perform some queries.  For some reason, when I quote a parameter before passing it to the query, I get back no rows.  When I pass it unquoted, it works fine.

Here's the relevant snippet of code I'm using:

```
  public function get($game)
  {
    load::helper('doctrinehelper');
    $conn = doctrinehelper::getconnection();
    $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT games.id as id, games.name as name, games.link_url, games.link_text, services.name as service_name, image_url 
                                 FROM games, services 
                                 WHERE games.name = ? 
                                 AND services.key = games.service_key');
    $quotedGame = $conn->quote($game);

    load::helper('loghelper');
    $logger = loghelper::getLogger();
    $logger->debug("Quoted Game: $quotedGame");
    $logger->debug("Unquoted Game: $game");

    $statement->execute(array($quotedGame));
    $resultsArray = $statement->fetchAll();
    $logger->debug("Number of rows returned: " . count($resultsArray));  
    return $resultsArray;
  }
```

Here's what the log shows:

```
01/01/11 17:00:13,269 [2112] DEBUG root - Quoted Game: 'Diablo II Lord of Destruction'
01/01/11 17:00:13,269 [2112] DEBUG root - Unquoted Game: Diablo II Lord of Destruction
01/01/11 17:00:13,270 [2112] DEBUG root - Number of rows returned: 0
```

If I change this line:

```
$statement->execute(array($quotedGame));
```

to this:

```
$statement->execute(array($game));
```

I get this in the log:

```
01/01/11 16:51:42,934 [2112] DEBUG root - Quoted Game: 'Diablo II Lord of Destruction'
01/01/11 16:51:42,935 [2112] DEBUG root - Unquoted Game: Diablo II Lord of Destruction
01/01/11 16:51:42,936 [2112] DEBUG root - Number of rows returned: 1
```

Have I fat-fingered something?

Comment: with quoting you're just adding some characters, making the string not mach one in the database. isn't it obvious?

Comment: I guess I don't understand how this works.  I've worked with Ibatis (a Java DB mapper) and it uses JDBC PreparedStatements to protect from SQL injection by default.  The DBAL docs (http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#update) seem to indicate that DBAL doesn't escape by default.  If quoting input parameters adds characters that cause queries to fail, under what circumstances should I quote?

Comment: as dr. said, there is no use for quoting at all, at least while you're using placeholders to put data into query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is an architectural thing (IMO). Doctrine is based on [PHP's PDO](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html?highlight=pdo#the-dbal-package). PDO works with Prepared Statements so there is no need to quote, use mysql_real_escapestring or anything. The ORM has has as a base design goal in it's very core and with PDO, it does this fairly secure.

Comment: I can't say it's VERY effective, thanks to calling database twice.